Black screen and frozen mouse after login on raspberry Pi3 + LTS24 + Desktop
I have installed ubuntu LTS24 on raspberry 3, it went OK. I just have a prompt command at the end.
Then the Ubuntu desktop (GUI), it took a while. Then rebooted.
I have the usual welcome graphic screen, that prompts for the password, but once entered, the screen is black, with a frozen mouse pointer.
After 2 minutes, it goes back to the welcome screen.
I can access to it via SSH anyway.
What can I do ?
journalctl -r (in red) ->
kernel: [drm:vc4_bo_create [vc4]] *ERROR* Failed to allocate from GEM DMA helper:
kernel: vc4-drm soc:gpu: [drm]                total purged BO:      8kb BOs (2)
kernel: vc4-drm soc:gpu: [drm]                         binner:  16384kb BOs (1)
kernel: vc4-drm soc:gpu: [drm]                           dumb:   3768kb BOs (2)
kernel: vc4-drm soc:gpu: [drm]                     V3D shader:     24kb BOs (6)
kernel: vc4-drm soc:gpu: [drm]                            V3D:  73108kb BOs (92)
gdm-password][3685]: gkr-pam: unable to locate daemon control file
systemd[3498]: Failed to start app-gnome-user\x2ddirs\x2dupdate\x2dgtk-4079.scope - Application launched by gnome-session-binary.


Look at journalctl -r outputs and look out for error messages
